# Fill cells with value from different ranges in the same column

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel with the following data:

```
**Input**                                    **Output**

| Column A | Column B |                      | Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |                      | -------- | -------- |
| larry    |          |                      | larry    |          |
| larry    |          |                      | larry    | 100      |
| 130      | 200      |                      | 130      | 200      |
| 130      | 100      |                      | 130      | 100      |
| josh     |          |                      | josh     |          |
| josh     |          |                      | josh     | 333      |
| 110      | 500      |                      | 110      | 500      |
| 110      | 459      |          -->         | 110      | 459      |
| 110      | 333      |                      | 110      | 333      |
| chris    |          |                      | chris    |          |
| chris    |          |                      | chris    | 30       |
| 120      | 222      |                      | 120      | 222      |
| 120      | 111      |                      | 120      | 111      |
| 120      | 77       |                      | 120      | 77       |
| 120      | 56       |                      | 120      | 56       |
| 120      | 30       |                      | 120      | 30       |
```

Using VBA, I have to fill the first blank cells from the bottom in Column B with the min value from the rows under it (with same values in Column A). The min value will always be at the last row for each range.

Any help would be appreciated.

I was able to fill up all blank cells with the values directly under it starting from the bottom. I'm not sure how to select a min value from a range and fill specific blank cells.

Comment: Is the quantity of adjacent blank cells always two?

Comment: @taller yes it is always two

Comment: For your real data, does it follow same pattern on Col A? eg. if the data row is 345 on Col A, then the blank cell is `No345`. (`No` + `Digits`)

Comment: no, it's just different names. The numbers under them will be their ID number like 130 but they will be the same for that range.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Use Dictionary object to get the min value
- Assuming the table starts from cell A1 on Sheet1, the quantity of adjacent blank cells is always TWO.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, arrData
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")  ' modify as needed
    Set rngData = oSht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' let data into an array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' loop through data to get the min of each group
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If Len(arrData(i, 2)) > 0 Then
            sKey = arrData(i, 1)
            If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                If arrData(i, 2) < objDic(sKey) Then objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 2)
            Else
                objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' populate the output
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If Len(arrData(i, 2)) = 0 Then
            sKey = arrData(i + 2, 1)
            If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                arrData(i + 1, 2) = objDic(sKey)
            End If
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next i
    ' write output to sheet
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a formula. Fill blank cells in column `B` with a formula (starting from `B2` if the first "larry" is in `A2`):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=2,MINIFS(B3:B$17,A3:A$17,A3),"")
```